# Ionic 1 AngularJs 1 vs Ionic 2 AngularJs 2?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I want to move from `IOS` to `Ionic`. But i don't have any idea that which version is best for starting, because i did't know nothing about `AngularJs 1` and its update version `AngularJs 2` features and differences. And also i did't find any related help from internet with difference of both versions. Can anyone please tell me pros and cons or difference between them. Or which one is best. And if `Ionic 2` is best so from where i can watch video tutorials of this.
Thanks

Comment: Trust me i just switched to Ionic 1 from ionic 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly the [podcast episode of Adventures in Angular](https://devchat.tv/adv-in-angular/088-aia-angular-style-guides), John Papa recommended starting new projects with Angular 2.

Since Ionic is built on top of Angular 2 it will be lagging a bit behind. If you want to go into production now with an Ionic 2 app I suppose it's not recommended using it. Since [Angular 2 is in RC](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) we might expect that they will release in the near future, and with that Ionic 2 will be some time behind that. Therefore, I recommend using Ionic 2 if you don't plan to go into production in the nearest future.

When it comes to the differences, [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/typed-front-end-with-angular-2) has a nice write up on the differences between Angular 1 and 2.

Edit: It's been a while since I wrote this post and I have followed the development of ionic 2. I would now recommend using ionic 2.

Answer (score 2):

Right now is quite unfortunate time to choose between Ionic/Angular v1 and v2. If you can afford that I would advise you to wait 1 year and the just pick Ionic 2. Most of the problems you will face today when dealing with Ionic/Angular 2 will be already solved here in stackoverflow 12 months from now.

Currently I would say it does not matter that much if you pick Ionic 1 or Ionic 2. In the first case you will move fast now, but waste time later trying to upgrade your app from ionic 1 to ionic 2. If you choose Ionic 2 now, you will waste similar amount of time just trying to make it work and adopt newer versions of Angular 2.

Answer (score 1):

if You beginner you can start ionic-1 and angular-1,because lots of resource available like angularJS essential , Inter mediator and advance video tutorial in youtube and many other training provider.

if you want to include oops concept and other important script like typescript,move on to ionic2.

Comment: You can use TypeScript with AngularJS 1 and Ionic 1 as well.

Comment: yes,but its included/introduce as library in angular2.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-21
you can check here all change log .

Comment: I think no need to start from ionic1, one can start directly ionic2. http://ionicmobile.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a mobile app, the question is ionic vs ionic 2 vs alternative frameworks.  A lot of work has gone to making ionic 2 fast, and unless you already have a lot of apps in ionic there is no point learning it now.

Regarding Angular 2, the benefit of Ionic is that you don't have to learn it to get started. You can create real apps using just Ionic, and when you do need Angular (for http for example) then there are plenty of examples around.

You can find videos on most of the pay learning sites, but to really learn it take an existing app such as https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app, which includes enough Angular 2 (Javascript and Typescript flavours) to see how a real app can be put together.

You can also play with the Ionic components with https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-preview-app.

The only reason for going Ionic 1 these days would be an edge case supporting an older version of Android, but if you need to go to a version earlier than 4.4 you will also find solutions that Ionic 2 can use.

================= UPDATE Jan 2017 ================

There is a great starter project which has a number of app features built in, such as app settings, api connection, registration and login, welcome tutorial which can be found here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-super